# Macros for reading .tif files

Tags: macros

I want to execute a Macro that can read what's there in a .tif     file and without opening an image we would know what's there in the image.

Pl. Help.

Vimmy Kapahi 
9910385889/8130355325

Comment: Please clarify the relationship of this posting to TeX and friends. Assuming there's a relationship, please clarify what you mean by "would know what's there in the image".

Comment: Welcome! What is the `9910385889/8130355325` for?

Answer (score 4):

The following example defines a macro `\ReadTifAsHexDump`, which reads the contents of the `.tif` file without opening it as image (for pdflatex only):

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\DeclareUrlCommand\hexdump{%
  \urlstyle{tt}%
  \def\UrlBreaks{%
    \do0\do1\do2\do3\do4\do5\do6\do7\do8\do9%
    \do A\do B\do C\do D\do E\do F%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\ReadTifAsHexDump}[1]{%
  \begin{flushleft}%
    \expandafter\hexdump\expandafter{%
      \pdffiledump length\pdffilesize{#1}{#1}%
    }%
  \end{flushleft}%
}
\begin{document}
  \ReadTifAsHexDump{test.tif}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

I admit, I have some doubts, that this hits the OP's intensions.
At least, the example shows the only way, how a binary file can be read in pdfTeX.
Vanilla TeX or XeTeX lack such a feature. LuaTeX can read binary files
through its Lua interface.